# Reassigning the case owner for certain cases after they reach a certain age?

Tags: case

I'm trying to have SF automatically re-assign cases whose titles contain a certain term to a new owner after they reach 24 hours of age. How would I be able to do that? I looked in the process builder but it doesn't have the ability to select age. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Processes run when a record is created or modified; there's no point in trying to select the age, because it would have to be at least 24 hours old *and* modified by a user. Instead, you can use [Case Escalation Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_escalation_rules.htm&language=en) to assign cases that have fallen out of SLA. If you wanted to use the Process Builder to handle complex assignment logic, you would simply need to set up a [Time-Based Workflow Rule](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_workflow_rules_configure_actions.htm&language=en_US) to force a field update, which in turn would cause your process to fire.

---

See this image for an example of how it might look like:

[image: Sample Escalation Rule]

Comment: It appears there is still no ability to select age in the Case Escalation Rules.

Comment: @AKor You have to create the rule, then create a rule entry, then create actions. It's the third part where you specify case age and the action to take, which can include reassignment and sending emails.

Comment: @AKor I even added a picture to demonstrate how it would appear once created.

Answer (score -1):

Couldn't you use a workflow. The criteria could be put in a formula like Createddate+1 AND CONTAINS(Titlefield, "titlevalue"). Then you could select Time-based Actions and use the field update option and select the Owner field and select the new Owner.

Comment: Not as an Immediate Action, because workflow rules only fire on an edit. But a Time-Based workflow rule could be built. That said, there's already a purpose-built feature called escalation rules that does that right out of the box.